# In C, why do I only need getchar() to remove characters sometimes?

Tags: c, if-statement, getchar

I am trying to use `getchar()` to remove characters from the input buffer. In the following code, the user is asked to input a choice to select, and then depending on the choice, another input is required, either type `int` or type `char` (string).

In the `int` case, `getcar()` is not needed and `scanf` takes in input correctly. But in the `char` case, `scanf` fails to get input without using `getchar()` beforehand. Is there a reason why that is?

```
printf("Available Ciphers:\n1) Caesar Cipher\n2) Vigenere Cipher\nSelected Cipher: ");
if(scanf("%d", &choice) != 1){
    printf("Error: Bad selection!\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
} else if (choice != 1 && choice != 2){
    printf("Error: Bad Selection!\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
//If the choice entered is correct, then run the following.
} else {
    if(choice == 1){
        printf("Input key as nuumber: ");
        if(scanf("%d", &caesarkey) != 1){ //Why is getchar() not needed here?
            printf("Error: Bad Key!\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        //morecode here
    } else if (choice == 2){
        printf("Input key as string: ");
        while(getchar() != '\n');  //Why is this needed here?
        /*Uses scanf and not fgets, since we do not want the
        key to contain the newline character '\n'. This is
        due to the fact that the newline character is not
        considered in the function that encrypts and decrypts
        plaintext and ciphertext.*/
        if(scanf("%[^\n]s", vigencipherkey) != 1){
            printf("Error, Cannot read inputted key!\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        //More code here..
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and it allows me to input something, but no matter what, I get the error message "Error, Cannot read inputted key!"

Comment: Do you really want that trailing s in that last `scanf()` format? You're better off using `fgets()` to read a line, anyways.

Comment: @Shawn I did that at first, but the function I wrote in another file doesn't take in to account the '\n' character, which is why I am using scanf.

Comment: @xing thank you for the answer, I didn't realise scanf leaves a newline character in the buffer. Thank you for clearing that up! ^^

Comment: You just remove the newline from the string if you don't want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are scanning for a string rather than an int, and as such, you are passing in an int rather than the address of an int.

Change this line

```
   if(scanf("%[^\n]s", vigencipherkey) != 1){
```

To

```
  if (scanf("%d", &vigencipherkey) != 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to read the remainder of the line input by the user, you can use this function:

```
int flush_line(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}
```

Notes:

- `c` must be defined as `int` to accommodate for all values of the type `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`.
- you should test for `'\n'` **and** `EOF` otherwise you will have an endless loop on premature end of file without a trailing newline, such as would occur  if you redirect the input of your program from an empty file.
- you can test for end of file by comparing the return value of `flush_line()` with `EOF`.